# Why are my water heater's hot and cold connections oriented opposite convention?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

I installed a 30 gallon Rheem water heater at one of my apartments. When I started to install the water lines, I noticed the right side indicated it was the hot side.  The HOT word was stamped in the metal on the right side. This was the opposite of any I ever installed. I have installed many over the years. I did not look down the pipe for the dip tube. I hesitated but followed the indicators . There was no red or blue tags on the heater. I installed it as indicated. It is working. However, it is disturbing and was wondering has anyone else seen this before.  It was annoying because I installed the lines for easy exchanges in the future but had to change my set up.  Thank you for any and all comments.

Comment: What model? Their [manuals](https://www.waterheaterhub.com/rheem-water-heater-manuals/) all seem to show hot on the left in the diagram.

Comment: I will take a ride back and check again. I ll let you know if I made a mistake.

Comment: You could verify it by removing the element ans seeing where the dip tube goes.  That really the only difference, I thnk.

Comment: Grab a photo of the top panel while you're there.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I did connect it correctly and the dip tube was correct. The old hot water tank has been recycled so I couldn t look at that. I believe the one I took out was improperly installed. That is why I had to reroute the pipes.